# Построение XML на основе HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml, парсер

Добрый день,

Дана HTML-страница с представлением иерархической структуры (построенной пользователем). Необходимо построить XML, в котором будет храниться эта структура, но в измененном виде (убрав все лишнее).

Получается нужно проходить по уровням HTML, находить нужные блоки и формировать новый XML.

Какими образом лучше реализовать данную задачу на C#? Что использовать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как обычно парсером, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Duoxx возможно какие-то подробные камни, и есть рекомендации, что нужно использовать. Парсить, как я понимаю, тоже можно по-разному.

Comment: И парсить HTML, и создавать XML можно, действительно, по-разному. Но чтобы дать вменяемый ответ, нужно знать структуру исходного html, нужно знать структуру желаемого итогового xml. Какой размер данных (может, гигабайты)? Каково количество страниц/файлов (может, миллионы)? Каковы требования к скорости работы, к потреблению памяти? Всегда ли html на входе корректен? Что делать в случае ошибок: падать, как-то иначе реагировать?